# Use Regex to INSERT text before and after a string pattern occurance

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I am trying to replace all series of " " chars with "< pre> < /pre>" using a regular expression in Javascript.

So I want to change the 1st line below to the second:

```
<p>There   should    be    gaps    of    4    chars    tween    each    word</p>
<p>There<pre>   </pre>should<pre>    </pre>be<pre>    </pre>gaps<pre>    </pre>of<pre>    </pre>4<pre>    </pre>chars<pre>    </pre>tween<pre>    </pre>each<pre>    </pre>word</p>

// Or if I cannot place <pre>'s inside a <p> element then replace them with 
// transparent "_" chars
<p>There<font style="color: transparent">____</font>should...</p>
```

*The reason I am doing this is because I am trying to preserve/display space chars and if I place the whole paragraph inside a pre element then word wrapping gets disabled.*

**Can you help me get my regular expression to place a pre start and end tag at the ends of each group of " " chars?**

```
var p = document.getElementById("myP");
var con = p.innerHTML;
con = con.replace(new RegExp("[ ]{2,}"), "<pre> ");
con = con.replace(new RegExp("[ ]{2,}"), " </pre>");
p.innerHTML = con;

// This is incorrect because it removes all the space chars and only leaves one there
// Test    string
// Test<pre> </pre>string // there should be 4 space chars here
```

Comment: Please see my last edit. Having better understood your problem, I hope you'll consider a CSS solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
con = con.replace(/(?:\s|&nbsp;)+/g, '&nbsp; &nbsp; ');
```

This has the advantage of matching any number of spaces (yours and [appclay's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9900382/17964) only matches 2 or more spaces), ensuring exactly 4 spaces ([ruakh's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9900390/17964) does not enforce the number of spaces), doesn't mix `<pre>` and `<p>`. The disadvantage of all of these is that they are unsafe with HTML attributes in the `innerHTML`, which may or may not be an issue for you. To solve that would require a parser or a DOM-based solution; if that's a concern, let me know in a comment and I could explain how to do it more safely in the DOM.

Edit: I've now accounted for other forms of whitespace (e.g. `\t` or `\n`) and existing `&nbsp;` (non-breaking-spaces).

Edit again, just noticed this:

> The reason I am doing this is because I am trying to preserve/display space chars and if I place the whole paragraph inside a pre element then word wrapping gets disabled.

If you don't need to support IE7 and below, you can add this style to the paragraph or its parent: `white-space: pre-wrap`. Then you could skip all of this text processing.

Answer (score 5):

Capture the match with `(` and `)` then reference it with `$1`

```
var p = document.getElementById("myP");
var con = p.innerHTML;
con = con.replace(/(\s{2,})/g, "<pre>$1</pre>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a group using brackets then reference it with $1...

```
var p = document.getElementById("myP");
var con = p.innerHTML;
con = con.replace(new RegExp("([ ]{2,})"), "<pre>$1</pre>");
p.innerHTML = con;
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than strewing `<pre>` elements in the middle of paragraphs, I think you'd be better off using non-breaking spaces:

```
con = con.replace(/  /g, /&nbsp; /);
```